# A RLWE promise problem

Tags: lwe

Let $(R , \chi$)  be a standard RLWE problem instance. I.e. $R$ is a finite degree polynomial ring over a finite field and $\chi$ is some gaussian distribution over R with small variance.

I wonder if the following promise problem is hard.
Let $a_0$ and $a_1$ be two random elements from $R$
The challenger choses a boolean $b$ and two elements $s,e \in \chi$,  and calculates $c= a_b s + e$.

The problem is then:
Given $c, a_0, a_1$, calculate $b$ with non-negible advantage.

For motivation:
If that promise problem turns out to be hard, one could use as natural PQ replacement of *PACE*, the password authenticated key agreement protocol used in electronic passports. (See 
[ICAO doc 9303](https://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/9303_p11_cons_en.pdf))

Comment: It feels like it ought to follow immediately from the standard rLWE assumption ("given $a$ and either $as + e$ or a random value $r$, it is hard to determine whether you received $as + e$ or $r$"); however I just can't see the reduction...

Comment: @poncho:  That is exactly my problem; I can also not see a reduction to RLWE decision. Meanwhile I think that this problem is weaker then RLWE decision/search.

Comment: If you're looking for a RLWE-based PAKE, there's https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/552.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the link. But I want to have a _natural_ replacement for _PACE_.

Comment: @Cryptostasis I think the use of a Boolean $b$ might make it weaker, but that could be contingent on the dimension of the lattice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(It seems that the proof can be salvaged.)

Let $\text{RLWE}$ denote the standard ring-LWE problem where the secret $s$ is drawn uniformly at random from $R$. Thus, the $\text{RLWE}$ assumption is: 
   $$(a,as+e)\approx(a,r):a,r,s\leftarrow R, e\leftarrow\chi,$$ 
where $\approx$ denotes computational indistinguishability. 
$\text{RLWE}$ assumption implies the *non-standard* LWE assumption [Lemma 2, ACPS09], denoted $\text{RLWE'}$, where the secret is drawn from $\chi$: 
  $$(a,as+e)\approx(a,r):a,r\leftarrow R, s,e\leftarrow\chi.$$ 
The hardness of the promise problem, denoted $\text{RLWE''}$, follows by a hybrid argument (see below) assuming $\text{RLWE'}$ holds. Thus, the chain of reduction is: 
 $$\text{RLWE}<\text{RLWE'}<\text{RLWE''}.$$

*The hybrid argument.* We want to show that the two distributions 
  $$D_L:=(a_0,a_1,a_0s+e) \text{ and } D_R:=(a_0,a_1,a_1s+e)$$
are computationally indistinguishable, for $a_0,a_1\leftarrow R$ and $s,e\leftarrow \chi$. Consider the hybrid distribution 
  $$D_H:=(a_0,a_1,r)$$ 
where $a_0,a_1,r\leftarrow R$. We show that $D_L\approx D_H$ and $D_H\approx D_R$, and it follows by transitivity that $D_L\approx D_R$.

To see that $D_L\approx D_H$, suppose for contradiction that it is not: that is there exists an algorithm $\mathsf{A}$ that distinguishes $D_L$ from $D_H$. We show that $\mathsf{A}$ can be used to break $\text{RLWE'}$. The reduction $\mathsf{R}$ is straightforward: given a $\text{RLWE'}$ challenge $(a,b)$ (where $a\leftarrow R$ and $b$ is either $as+e$ or $r$), $\mathsf{R}$ samples $a'\leftarrow R$ and sends $(a,a',b)$ to $\mathsf{A}$ and outputs to its challenger whatever $\mathsf{A}$ outputs. If $b=as+e$ then $\mathsf{A}$ simulates $D_L$; otherwise it simulates $D_H$.

The argument showing $D_H\approx D_R$ is similar.

References.

[[ACPS09]](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/kdm-learning.pdf) Applebaum, Cash, Peikert and Sahai. Fast Cryptographic Primitives and Circular-Secure Encryption Based on Hard Learning Problems. CRYPTO 2009.

Comment: In the question, I presume that $s\leftarrow\chi$ is a mistake.

Comment: No, $s \leftarrow \chi$ is correct, see the NewHope paper  https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1092.pdf

Comment: Ah. Then I don't think the above argument holds.

Comment: The proof can be salvaged, it seems.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was nonsense. I removed it.

Comment: I am still not sure if your argument holds. But it as written in a clean professional style. I therefore award you the bounty.

Comment: Are you not convinced with the hybrid argument? I can try to rewrite it in a cleaner manner.